# Eclipse Subversion Password not being saved

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

For some reason, my subclipse in Eclipse is asking for my password **ALL THE TIME**. Even after I have checked the 'Save Password' checkbox :

[image]

This never happened before, and only now has happened since I changed my password on TSS.

If I select the 'save password' checkbox then there is a pause for about 3 minutes, and a dialog pops up asking :

[image]

No matter if I select YES or NO there is no difference. However I can still perform my SVN operations even after all this time. The "Mark as Merged" also takes a whopping 5 minutes to perform. I have no idea what is going on here.

This is awful and I cannot work like this. I am thinking of reinstalling my project because of this.

Comment: The subversion passwords are usually stored by subversion, not by Eclipse. Therefore they are not part of your Eclipse workspace und in the `~/.subversion`directory respectively `%AppData%\Subversion` on Windows.

Comment: Maybe you do not have write access to %AppData%\Subversion?  Also, SVN uses a Windows API to encrypt your password.  I have never seen this fail before, but the fact that you were prompted seems like it did.  I guess you could make sure you are using JavaHL and not SVNKit.  That might change things.  You can see this in preferences Team > SVN

Comment: ha! I saw that i was using JavaHL, so I switched over to SVNKit to see what would happen, and now it works :)

Comment: SVNKit stores its passwords differently, so the suggestions about %AppData% could still be the root cause for JavaHL.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the entry at `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` and the problem will disappear.